# Karate - Post response based on previous request

Tags: http, post, karate

I'm trying to create a multi-part scenario using karate and graphql - using responses to form the next query.  I have looked extensively through the docs but can't seem to make sense of it.

I've looked at the doc which says "Given path ..." and then run the second query as a get but I need to use the same path

I'm trying to do the following:

- log in a get `authId` - this is done in the background using a "call read" to another feature file containing the login
- request a query from our internal graphql server using a requestid
- retrieve the `workId` from the response
- use this `workId` to run a mutation graphql and change the database
- retrieve the response and validate the change has been made successfully

I'm unable to post the exact schemas and codes for security reasons but, to give you a vague idea of what i'm trying to do:

```
Background:
    * url serverBaseUri
    * def signIn = call read('classpath:somepath/to_login.feature') { username: 'abc', password: '123', result: true }
    * def sessionAccessId = signIn.responseHeaders['set-cookie'][0]
    * header Cookie = sessionAccessId


Scenario: 'Multi Lookup Value test'

* def reqID = "32443rw"

### Send query to get work id from request id as its dynamic and is required to modify the request.
* def query = 
"""
 query {
                RequestById(id: "<reqID>"){
                        workId
                        otherNotes
                      }
                  }

"""

Given request { query: '#(query)' }
When method post
Then status 200

#### Extract work id from response

* def wkId = response.data.RequestById.workId 

### populate 'otherNotes' and 'assignee' for workflow

* def queryMutate = 
"""
        mutation {
                  ModifyRequest(
                              requestId: "<reqID>"
                              workId: "<wkId>",
                              assignee: "testUser"
                              otherNotes: "test"
                  }
    """

Given request { query: '#(queryMutate)' }
When method post
Then status 200
And match $ ==
"""
{
    "data": {
      "completeRequest": true
    }
  }
"""

### Verify query changed successfully


* def validateMutationsWorked = 
"""
 query {
                RequestById(id: "<reqID>"){
                        workflowId
                        otherNotes
                      }
                  }

"""

Given request { query: '#(validateMutationsWorked)' }
When method post
Then status 200
And match $ ==
"""
{
                  "data": {
                    "Requests": [
                      {
                        "requestId": "32443rw",
                        "workId": "abc",
                        "assignee": null,
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }

"""
```

So, essentially, I have 3 given statements in my scenario which need to follow in sequence. Hope that makes a bit more sense and adds the requested detail.

Comment: voting to close as too broad. my suggestion is come up with a sample so that you can ask specific question. why don't you use this as a starting point: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/graphql/graphql.feature

Comment: its a bit hard to come up with a sample if its not working but i'll try paste something that doesn't work to the original comment.

Comment: Added some details hopefully that's better explains my situation. I can try and elaborate more if it still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the `replace` keyword: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace

```
* def text = 'hello <foo> world'
* replace text.foo = 'bar'
* match text == 'hello bar world'
```

And where you have `queryMutate` please use `text`. All this is extensively covered in the documentation, you should really take the time to read it: https://github.com/intuit/karate#text

```
* def reqID = "32443rw"
* text query = 
"""
query {
  RequestById(id: "<reqID>") {
    workId
    otherNotes
  }
}
"""
* replace query.reqID = reqID
Given request { query: '#(query)' }
```

Comment: Hi,  Ive added the background tag i'm using - I'm finding when i run multiple given statments - the 1st runs correctly, the 2nd one errors with "invalid login" so its not correctly using the header tag from the background for consecutive requests

So, the question was can a scenario be run with mutiple given statements in this was or should i run it in a different way.

Comment: @jagradang I'm sorry this info is not useful at all. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue